# akka.actor.ActorLogging does not log the stack trace of exception by logback

Tags: scala, akka, logback

I am using `Logback + SLF4J` to do logging for those actors with trait of `akka.actor.ActorLogging`. However, when I do the code `log.error("Error occur!", e)`, the stack trace of the exception `e` is not logged, but only print a line of `Error occur!  WARNING arguments left: 1`. I wonder why and how to print the stack trace in the log file. Thank you. The following is my `logback.groovy` file configuration.

```
appender("FILE", RollingFileAppender) {
  file = "./logs/logd.txt"
  append = true
  rollingPolicy(TimeBasedRollingPolicy) {
    fileNamePattern = "./logs/logd.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
    maxHistory = 30
  }
  encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
    pattern = "%date{ISO8601} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} %X{sourceThread} - %msg%n"
  }
}
root(DEBUG, ["FILE"])
```

Comment: I faced the same issue. As a temporary solution I just replaced `ActorLogging` with `LazyLogging` (provided by typesafe.scalalogging) and `log.` with `logger.` in all my actors. But be aware that by doing so you will loose actor address string in the log. So this could be used until the real solution is found.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Akka has separate logging, which is configured in Akka's application.conf. If you want bridge to SLF4J/Logback - use thеsе settings:

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
}
```

See: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/logging.html

As far as I can see [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/event/Logging.scala), reason (Throwable) should be the first argument of `log.error`:

```
 def error(cause: Throwable, message: String)
```

That's why you see "WARNING arguments left" - your Throwable argument was just ignored.

Comment: For the newer akka version (2.2+) this must be `loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]` according to [this migrating guide](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2-M1/project/migration-guide-2.1.x-2.2.x.html) But this still does not solve the issue with exception stack trace logging.

Comment: Question was edited, so i didn't see the update about stacktrace. I think the reason is just incorrect usage of log.error - edited my answer.

Comment: Ya same problem here - throwable should be first argument, not last.

Answer (score 0):

The 'cause' exception should be the first argument to `error`, not the second (as correctly mentioned by JasonG in a comment on another answer).

Using the Akka log system instead of 'bare' scala-logging has some advantages around automatically added metadata and easier testing/filtering.

See also:

- http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/scala/logging.html
- http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/akka/event/LoggingAdapter.html#error(cause:Throwable,message:String):Unit